# How to fix system.log filling up with servermgrd "Record of type dsRecTypeStandard:Config named 'ServicesInformation101004'?

Tags: osx-server, leopard

#### Record of type dsRecTypeStandard:Config ... already exists in /Local/Default

I passed by a Mac OS X Leopard server (10.5.8) that is no longer accessible via SSH neither ARD. CPU load is maxing out and the system log is filling with these messages:

> xserve servermgrd[66]: Record of type dsRecTypeStandard:Config named
> 'ServicesInformation101006' already exists in /Local/Default. Trying
> with new name: ServicesInformation101007
>
> xserve servermgrd[66]: Record of type dsRecTypeStandard:Config named
> 'ServicesInformation101007' already exists in /Local/Default. Trying
> with new name: ServicesInformation101008

How to fix this OS X server?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because OS X is creating lots of files in:

```
/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/config
```

#### Delete files from Terminal

Due to  the high number of files involved don't use Finder but use Terminal instead.

```
$ cd /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/config
```

#### Permission denied

You might have difficulty doing this due to not having enough permissions to enter that folder, in that case get yourself super powers:

```
$ sudo su
```

#### Delete files

You need to delete all of the `ServicesInformation....` files, for example:

```
$ rm ServicesInformation*
```

#### Too many matches

You probably are not able delete all files in one run due to the high number of matches. In that case do delete the files more selectively. In my case, this worked:

```
$ rm ServicesInformation1{1,2,3}*
$ rm ServicesInformation1*
$ rm ServicesInformation2{1,2,3}*
$ rm ServicesInformation2*
...
```

#### Reboot

And my the message is gone from system.log and the CPU usage has gone from 100% to below 1%.

partial source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1481182?start=45&tstart=0